# Is it possible to express the number $\;\arctan \left(\sqrt{7-4 \sqrt{2}}\right)-\arctan \left(\sqrt{4 \sqrt{2}+7}\right)$ in a compact form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I obtained this number in *Mathematica*:

$$\text{number}=\arctan \left(\sqrt{7-4 \sqrt{2}}\right)-\arctan \left(\sqrt{4 \sqrt{2}+7}\right)$$

I would like to write it in a more compact form (if possible); using `FullSimplify` it gives in terms of `Root[1 - 5 #^2 + 2 #^4& , 2, 0]`.

Is it possible to express this number in a more compact form and not in terms of `Root`?

```
num :=    ArcTan[Sqrt[7 - 4 Sqrt[2]]] -  ArcTan[Sqrt[7 + 4 Sqrt[2]]];

{   num//FullSimplify  , num//N }

(* {ArcTan[Root[1 - 5 #^2 + 2 #^4& , 2, 0]], -0.437896} *)
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague, in the sense that I don't understand what you mean by more compact form, but `num // TrigToExp` gives an answer in terms of logarithms. Not sure if it helps

Comment: `Manipulate[Rationalize[num, 10^-i]
 , {{i, 1}, 1, 20}
 ]`

Comment: Using: https://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html ,I have: `-1/4 ArcCos[1/16*(-7 + Sqrt[17])]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

num = ArcTan[Sqrt[7 - 4 Sqrt[2]]] - ArcTan[Sqrt[7 + 4 Sqrt[2]]];

num2 = num // FullSimplify // ToRadicals

(* -ArcTan[Sqrt[5 - Sqrt[17]]/2] *)

num3 = num2 // FullSimplify

(* -ArcCot[Sqrt[1/2 (5 + Sqrt[17])]] *)

num == num2 == num3 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```